# Xamarin Forms No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Sku', or mismatching type between value and property

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin project I have a custom button controller:

```cs
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public class AddToCartButton : Button
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty SkuPoperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Sku), typeof(ApiModels.SkuDetailModel), typeof(AddToCartButton));

        public ApiModels.SkuDetailModel Sku
        {
            get { return (ApiModels.SkuDetailModel)GetValue(SkuPoperty); }
            set { SetValue(SkuPoperty, value); }
        }

        public AddToCartButton()
        {
            this.Clicked += AddToCartButton_Clicked;
        }

        public AddToCartButton(ApiModels.SkuDetailModel sku)
        {
            this.Sku = sku;
            this.Clicked += AddToCartButton_Clicked;
        }

        private async void AddToCartButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var response = await Helpers.ApiHelper.CurrentAccess.AddToCart(new List<ApiModels.CartItem>() {
                new ApiModels.CartItem() {
                    ItemCode = Sku.ItemCode,
                    Quantity = 1
                }
            });
            // handle add modal
        }
    }
```

This is the exact same way I've created BindableProperties for ContentViews and what have you.

In my xaml referencing this controller, I have:

```cs
<local:AddToCartButton Text="Add to Cart" Style="{ DynamicResource SkuAddToCart }" Sku="{Binding Sku}" />
```

This line is causing my builds to fail, with the error:
`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Position 44:44. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Sku', or mismatching type between value and property....`

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting it. All my types are consistent. The object I'm trying to bind is done like this:

    public partial class SkuView : ContentView
        {
            public ApiModels.SkuDetailModel Sku { get; set; }

```cs
        public SkuView(ApiModels.SkuDetailModel sku, string baseUrl, ApiModels.SimpleUser user)
        {
            BindingContext = this;
            Sku = sku;
            InitializeComponent();
```

Per request for xaml headers, here is the entire xaml file.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

```cs
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myApp.Controls"
         x:Class="myApp.Views.Products.SkuView">
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid Style="{ DynamicResource SkuGrid }">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackLayout x:Name="ImageCell" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></StackLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="ContentCell" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                <Label x:Name="DescriptionLabel" Style="{ DynamicResource SkuDescLabel }" />
                <Label x:Name="ItemCodeLabel" Style="{ DynamicResource SkuItemCode }" />
                <StackLayout x:Name="PricingLayout">
                    <!--<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label x:Name="PriceLabel" Style="{ DynamicResource SkuPricing }" />
                        <Label x:Name="PurchaseMultipleLabel" Style="{ DynamicResource SkuUom }" />
                    </StackLayout>-->
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Button Text=" - " Style="{ DynamicResource SkuQtyStepper }" />
                    <Grid Margin="-10, 0">
                        <BoxView Color="DarkGray" Opacity=".6" Margin="0, 5"/>
                        <BoxView Color="White" Margin="2, 7"/>
                        <local:BorderlessEntry Style="{ DynamicResource SkuQtyEntry }" Keyboard="Numeric" Margin="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Button Text=" + " Style="{ DynamicResource SkuQtyStepper }" />
                </StackLayout>
                <!--<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Button Text=" - " Style="{ DynamicResource SkuQtyStepper }" />
                    <local:BorderedEntry Style="{ DynamicResource SkuQtyEntry }" Keyboard="Numeric" HeightRequest="20" />
                    <Button Text=" + " Style="{ DynamicResource SkuQtyStepper }" />
                </StackLayout>-->
                <local:AddToCartButton Text="Add to Cart" Style="{ DynamicResource SkuAddToCart }" Sku="{Binding Sku}" />
                <!--<Button Text="Add to Cart" Style="{ DynamicResource SkuAddToCart }" />-->
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>

        <Grid HeightRequest="1" Style="{ DynamicResource BackgroundMediumGray }" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

Comment: can you post the xaml headers ?

Comment: @Greggz I have included the whole file for you

Comment: Could you try it like this `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myApp.Controls;assembly=myApp"`

Comment: @Greggz Tried that, no difference. Except, I've lost my intellisence for the `Sku` Bindable Property if that matters;

Comment: SkuView is initialized properly ?

Comment: Everything seems fine..

Comment: @Greggz My thoughts exactly... Can't figure out what's going on.
SkuView is initialized like so...
`Stack.Children.Add(new SkuView(sku, siteAddress, user));`

Comment: Well, try to remove this line `[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]`.. Tell me what happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163874/discussion-between-nieminen-and-greggz).

Comment: For me its not running without the static keyword before bindableproperty

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In the property name, you have a typo:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty SkuPoperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Sku), typeof(ApiModels.SkuDetailModel), typeof(AddToCartButton));
```

SkuPoperty  => **SkuProperty**

Edit:
To elaborate, Xamarin requires to have PropertyName**Property** naming convention:
[Creating a bindable property](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties/#Creating_a_Property)

Comment: It's not. He uses `Poperty` everywhere

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. Apparently Xamarin requires a specific naming convention for those properties. Stupid, even though I have the proper reference everywhere.

Comment: Just glad it works. As stupid as it is. Moral of the story - Spellcheck.

Comment: @Greggz Actually, I didn't notice that he used `Poperty` everywhere, just the first one :D and yeah, [Xamarin requires a Property naming convention](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties/#Creating_a_Property)

Comment: My property Name was correctly spelled and was in the proper convention but still, it was not working after going through this answer I changed my property name from EntryTextProperty to Just TextPropertyand now it works.

Comment: hats off for emphasizing the PropertyNameProperty naming convention.

Comment: I had my BindableProperty as private.  It needed to be public.