# No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "HeightRequest", or mismatching type between value and property error in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, compiler-errors

Not a duplicate of [Xamarin Forms No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Sku', or mismatching type between value and property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432840/xamarin-forms-no-property-bindable-property-or-event-found-for-sku-or-misma)

I am completely new to Xamarin.Forms and am trying my first `Hello World` app.
I wrote the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="hello_world.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welome" 
            BackgroundColor="Yellow" 
            TextColor="Green" 
            HeightRequest="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, Factor=0.05, Constant=0}"
            FontSize="Medium" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

However, I am receiving the error

```
No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "HeightRequest", or mismatching type between value and property.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting `Label` inside [StackLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stacklayout), while the value you use like `{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, Factor=0.05, Constant=0}` is using for [relativelayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout).

These are two different layouts and you can't mix them. Read the document and check the examples there to learn how to use them.

Feel free to ask me any question if you have:).

Update code:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Label 
        Text="Welome" 
        BackgroundColor="Yellow" 
        TextColor="Green" 
        FontSize="Medium"

        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"

        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, Factor=0.05,Property= Height, Constant=0}"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Well, this might even have been an XY-problem. What I basically want to do is to set the height of the label to 5% of the rendering device's height

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 You should use RelativeLayout, see my updated code.

Comment: I actually don't remember the exact post (Somewhere here), but there was a well-UVed comment there saying try to avoid relative layout as much as you can.

Comment: If you want to achieve `set the height of the label to 5% of the rendering device's height`, the RelativeLayout is the better choice than others.

Comment: Every layout has advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221853/discussion-between-jack-hua-msft-and-d4rk4ng31).

Answer (score 1):

> What I basically want to do is to set the height of the label to 5% of
> the rendering device's height

Ok, so if this is only your concern then use it like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Label 
        Text="Welome" 
        BackgroundColor="Yellow" 
        TextColor="Green"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0.05,Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0.05,Constant=0}"
        FontSize="Medium" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The exception you are facing is because of wrong syntax. And you have to replace your parent layout with **RelativeLayout** instead of StackLayout

Answer (score 0):

Beg your pardon `HeightRequest` is a bindable property.
Your case is "mismatching type between value and property", it can only be `double`, you cannot bind it to a `ConstraintExpression`.

Comment: Please elaborate on *Your case is "mismatching type between value and property", it can only be double, you cannot bind it to a ConstraintExpression*

Comment: The above answers your question "Where am I going wrong?"

Comment: What I meant was, what is a bindable-property?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/