# How does one position elements in RelativeLayout in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-relativelayout

I relation to my question [No property, BindableProperty, or event found for “HeightRequest”, or mismatching type between value and property error in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003252/no-property-bindableproperty-or-event-found-for-heightrequest-or-mismatchin), is there any way I can place the username and password `entry` elements right below the Welcome Label?

So, basically, the app should look like:

```
[Welcome Label]




  [username]
  [password]


   [login]
```

I tried using

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Label
        Text="Welcome" 
        BackgroundColor="Yellow" 
        TextColor="Green" 
        FontSize="Medium"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Factor=1, Property=Width, Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Factor=0.1, Property=Height, Constant=0}"
    />

    <Entry
        Text="Username"
        IsPassword="False"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

(Currently just the username field) but to no avail. Why is the entry field being placed over the label?

Comment: if you don't specify any constraints it's just going to stack the elements.  A StackLayout or Grid might make more sense for your use case

Comment: if you're new I'd suggest you start with StackLayout, it is much simpler

Comment: @Jason, Hmm... then how will I achieve central alignment?

Comment: then use a Grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [RelativeToView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout#relative-positioning-and-sizing) property to indicate a constraint that is relative to a view

```
<RelativeLayout>
        <Label
            x:Name="label"
            Text="Welcome" 
            BackgroundColor="Yellow" 
            TextColor="Green" 
            FontSize="Medium"
            WidthRequest="100"
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Factor=1, Property=Width, Constant=1}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Factor=0.1, Property=Height, Constant=0}"
            />

        <Entry
            x:Name="name"
            Text="Username"
            IsPassword="False"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=label,Property=Width,Factor=0.50,Constant=-50}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=label,Property=Y ,Constant=200}"

            />
        <Entry
            x:Name="password"
            Text="Password"
            IsPassword="False"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=name,Property=X}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=name,Property=Y ,Constant=50}"
            />
        <Button Text="Login" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=password,Property=X}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=password,Property=Y ,Constant=200}"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

effect like:

[image]

Comment: Great. Understood. Just one question. How do we select a right constant to add to the factor?

Comment: Also why did you select Property=X and not Width (as in Property=Width)?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 It depends on your needs，forexample,you want to a  specific constant offset ,you could set to constant,like 10,20,30...If you want a percentage deviation,you could set to factor,like 0.5(50%),0,33(33%)...

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 First XConstraint is used to constrain the entry position on the X-axis，then RelativeToView   and  Property=Width is mean the offset value is 50% width of the label,you could see the entry will position from the half of label's width.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Yes,you could read more in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout#constraint-markup-extension).There is the description of the markup extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try making something like this & change the alignment according to you.

```
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Label Text="Welcome" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="10, 30, 0, 0"/>
                <Entry Placeholder="User Id" Margin="10, 20, 0, 0"/>
                <Entry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True" Margin="10"/>
                <Button Text="Login" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
```

I used stack layout just for basic purpose, its not perfect UI but just for reference.