# Error XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "LeftSetsValue", or mismatching type between value and property

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, maui

I am working on the MAUI application. I have created a content view as a custom control. That content View has 2 entry controls. I want to bind those entries from the content Page. I performed the below code but I am getting an error.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty LeftSetsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(LeftSetsValue), typeof(string), typeof(ExerciseSelection), string.Empty, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);
    
public string LeftSetsValue
{
    get => (string)GetValue(LeftSetsProperty);
    set => SetValue(LeftSetsProperty, value);
}
```

```xml
<Entry Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" MaxLength="3" TextColor="Black" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding LeftSetsValue, Source={x:Reference exerciseSelectionControl}}" />
```

In the Content Page, I am using this control like this

```xml
<controls:ExerciseSelection Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,90,0" ExerciseName="EMPTY CAN" ClassId="emptycan" ExerciseClicked="ExerciseButton_Clicked" LeftSetsValue="{Binding SharedVM.LeftSetForExptyCan}"/>
```

In ViewModel, I created the property like this,

```
private string _leftSetForExptyCan;
    public string LeftSetForExptyCan
    {
        get => _leftSetForExptyCan;
        set
        {
            if (_leftSetForExptyCan != value)
            {
                _leftSetForExptyCan = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LeftSetForExptyCan));
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting the below error. I can't figure out what's the issue.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for
> "LeftSetsValue", or mismatching type between value and
> property. ...\Pages\HomePage.xaml 60

Comment: There are numerous existing question on this error.  Have you read them?

Comment: Yes, I have gone through several links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432840/xamarin-forms-no-property-bindable-property-or-event-found-for-sku-or-misma

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/478718/error-xfc0009-no-property-bindableproperty-or-even.html

https://xamarin21.rssing.com/chan-23562832/all_p7302.html

Comment: the very **first** link in your comment has an answer with **35 upvotes** that explains the naming convention for bindable properties

Comment: @Jason You are right. 
The naming convention is working like this, For bindable property name should be ABCProperty and your property name should be ABC.

Comment: I didn't understand the first article properly. I don't have a typo in "Property". So, I thought it is not my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change your `BindableProperty` name to "LeftSetsValueProperty":

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty LeftSetsValueProperty = ...
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#create-a-property) states:

> **Important**
>
> The naming convention for bindable properties is that the bindable property identifier must match the property name specified in the `Create` method, with "Property" appended to it.